Missing solutions from $y'(x)^2 = 2 y(x) y''(x)$
I am looking into this ODE: $y'(x)^2 = 2 y(x) y''(x)$, and I find some solutions through the following steps:
$$ \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} = 2 \frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}$$
This suggests that by integration I should have
$$ \ln( y(x)) = 2 \ln( y'(x) ) + C_0 $$
$$ y(x) = \lambda y'(x)^2 $$
with $\lambda = e^{C_0}$
Again, this suggests 2 possible pairs of signs:
$$ \pm \lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{y'(x)}{ \pm \sqrt{y(x)}} $$
By integrating, I get 2 possible solutions:
$$ \pm \lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} x + C_1 = \ln{ \left| \sqrt{y(x)} \right| }$$
$$ y(x) = e^{\pm 2 \lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} x + C_1}$$
where $C_1$ is allowed to be complex.
These are certainly solutions, but apparently this procedure does not capture all possible solutions. In fact, if $y(x) = x^n$, then we have
$$ n \frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{n}} = 2 \frac{ (n - 1) x^{n-2}}{x^{n-1}} $$
which is a solution if $n = 2n - 2$, which has a solution for $n=2$
So my question is here: why are these polynomial solutions missed from my 1st attempt at solving the ODE? If the procedure misses polynomial solutions, what other solutions might be also amiss?

You should reevaluate your statement: $$\int\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}} = \log|\sqrt{y}|$$ You "missed" solutions because you didn't find a correct one.

ugh, you are right @NinadMunshi that step was invalid

If you work out the right answer, I would encourage you to post it as an answer to your own question.
